# Copying a source column to two destination columns in AWS DMS

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-dms

I have a source database that I am trying to replicate using AWS DMS.

In the source database there is table `t` with column `c VARCHAR(100)`

I want to copy `source.t.c` into two columns in the destination: `destination.t.c` and `destination.t.another_c` (ie two columns **in the same table**)

Note that:

- `destination.t.c` has the same datatype as `source.t.c`
- `destination.t.another_c` is `VARCHAR(50)` - truncation of data isn't a problem

I have tried this rule in the DMS configuration:

```json
{
    "rule-type": "transformation",
    "rule-id": "2",
    "rule-name": "2",
    "rule-action": "add-column",
    "rule-target": "column",
    "object-locator": {
        "schema-name": "Test",
        "table-name": "t"
    },
    "value": "another_c",
    "expression": "$c",
    "data-type": {
        "type": "string",
        "length": 50
    }
}
```

But get `the metadata transformations defined for table 't' were not performed as at least one of the transformation expressions contains an error`.

Is there anything obviously wrong with the transformation rule? Is this the correct way to achieve what I want? Does a difference in datatype have any influence?

(just in case it's pertinent, this is from Aurora MySQL 2 to Aurora MySQL 3)

Update: I should have said, this is for a continuous synchronisation rather than a one-off copy.

Comment: Maybe just duplicate the column after the transfer? `UPDATE t set another_c = c`

Comment: Yes, that would work but this is a continuous synchronisation, rather than a one-off. It's a good point, I'll update the question. Thanks for the suggestion!